# Pass parameter value between pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Anyone help me please as I do not know how to code this. I have try but it do not work.

[image]

```
 function addRowHandlers() {
 var tbody = $("#employee-click"); //document.getElementById("employee- 
 click");
 tbody.each(function() {
 $(this).on('click', function() {     

      var passthis = $(this).find("#employee-grid").html();

   $.post("detail.php",

          {sessionval: passthis},

    function(e) { window.location.href ="detail.php?no="+passthis;}

   );

   })
  })
  }
```

For the php code is like this which is in the different page called detail.php

```
   <?php


   if (isset($_GET['no']))
   $no= $_GET['no'];

   else
   $no = 0;

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT no,svcno,pangkat,name
    FROM av
     WHERE no = $no";

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL error');
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)

     ?>
```

How to do the parameter value that can have the php code to show the detail value, so that there is no error? guide me please. I have redo the code for a long time but do not find the solution yet.

Comment: no ="undefined" that's the problem, not details page

Comment: "How do you eat an elephant?"  "One bite at a time."  You're trying to solve more than one thing at a time.  I would start with a page that simply makes an sql call and shows it.  (That means learning how to properly use `mysqli` or `PDO` ***with prepared statements***.  The command you're using is outdated and hopefully will be removed soon.)  Once you figure out how to display database contents, then send variables through a form with `$_POST` or `$_GET`.  After you master that, then attack AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below modified version. The code binds a click handler to all rows. And when the row is clicked, the page is redirected to detail.php page with a valid `no` parameter value.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    $('#employee-grid').on('click', 'tr', function() { 
      var data = dataTable.row(this).data();
      var passthis = data[0];
      $.post("detail.php", {
          sessionval: passthis
        },
        function(e) {
          window.location.href = "detail.php?no=" + passthis;
        }
      );
    });
}
```

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: The code is still error. Any other solution, please?

Comment: Can you pastebin the code for Datatable() and addRowHandlers()?

Comment: I think some code should be added to this code 
      var passthis = $(this).find("#employee-grid").html(); but what the code that should be added?

Comment: the code for datatable $(document).ready(function() {
    
    
   var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "dataBiodata.php", // json datasource
     
   
    } );

Comment: code for data handlers                                                               
 function addRowHandlers() {
 var tbody = $("#employee-click"); //document.getElementById("employee- click");
 tbody.each(function() {
 $(this).on('click', function() {     

      var passthis = $(this).find("#employee-grid").data();

   $.post("detail.php",

          {sessionval: passthis},

    function(e) { window.location.href ="detail.php?no="+passthis;}

   );

   })
  })
  }

Comment: please help me. i do not know how to do that. i have search throughout the websites but i cannot find anything that related with this code.

Comment: Updated my answer. Pls check.

Comment: it cannot be click at all.what just happen?

Comment: What error does the console says? Do you have web developer tool there?

Comment: the row just cannot be click at all. i do not have web developer  tool there. may you fix the coding for me please. do you have email?later, i send to you the code.

Comment: What's your email?

Comment: If you're using chrome it has Developer tools you can use to debug.

Answer (score 0):

with data-table to get row id on click you can below code, this is just example

code with data-tables:

```
$(document).on('click', '#closingDatesTable tbody tr', function() {
 var row_id = $(this).attr('id');
 window.location.href = "detail.php?no=" + row_id;
});
```

Comment: i have try but it don't work.

Comment: did you change the id and are you using data-tables now?